# How to test this with Jasmine test (Behaviour Driven Development)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, bdd

I've just developed this JavaScript/Backbone module as a part of a web page I am developing. I would like to create a Jasmine test for it, but I am brand new to Jasmine, therefore I am not sure what should I be testing in this class. What should be the "skeleton" of the test? In order to avoid redundancy in tests, what parts will you test?

editdestinationview.js:

```
define([
    'common/jqueryex',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'handlebars',
    'text!education/eet/templates/editdestination.hb',
    'text!common/templates/validationerror.hb',
    'lang/languageinclude',
    'common/i18nhelper'
], function ($, Backbone, Marionette, Handlebars, templateSource, errorTemplateSource, i18n) {
    'use strict';

    var errorTemplate = Handlebars.compile(errorTemplateSource),
        EditDestinationView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

            initialize: function (options) {
                this._destinationTypes = options.destinationTypes;
            },

            onRender: function () {
                this.stickit();
                this._bindValidation();
            },

            _bindValidation: function () {
                Backbone.Validation.bind(this, {
                    valid: this._validAttributeCallback,
                    invalid: this._invalidAttributeCallback,
                    forceUpdate: true
                });
            },

            _validAttributeCallback: function (view, attr) {
                view.$('#error-message-' + attr).remove();
            },

            _invalidAttributeCallback: function (view, attr, error) {
                view.$('#error-message-' + attr).remove();
                view.$('#destinationTypes').parent('div').append(errorTemplate({
                    attr: attr,
                    error: error
                }));
            },

            template: Handlebars.compile(templateSource),

            ui: {
                saveAnchor: '#ed_eetSaveDestinationAnchor',
                deleteAnchor: '#ed_eetDeleteDestinationIcon'
            },

            triggers: {
                'click @ui.saveAnchor': 'click:saveDestination',
                'click @ui.deleteAnchor': 'click:deleteDestination'
            },

            bindings: {
                'select#destinationTypes': {
                    observe: 'destinationTypeId',
                    selectOptions: {
                        collection: function () {
                            return this._destinationTypes;
                        },
                        labelPath: 'description',
                        valuePath: 'destinationTypeId',
                        defaultOption: {label: i18n.EDUCATION_EET_SELECT_INTENDED_DESTINATION, value: null}
                    }
                }
            }

        });

    return EditDestinationView;
});
```

Thanks everyone!

**UPDATE:**
After thinking a lot about it, I think that I should try these aspects:
-Triggers: Check if they can be clicked.
-"_validAttributeCallback" and "_invalidAttributeCallback": Check if they behave accordingly to the code.
-Template: Spy on it to check if it is performing it's mission. (Optional test)

So, the test skeleton will be:

```
define([
    'education/eet/views/editdestinationview'
], function (EditDestinationView) {

    describe('description...', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            //EditDestinationView.triggers
        });

        describe('blablabla', function () {

            beforeEach(function () {
//                ...
            });

            it('blablabla', function () {
//      blablabla
            });

        });
    });

});
```

Any help on how to test this please?

Answer (score 1):

One common pattern is to use two `describe` statements, one for the class and one for the method being tested, and then an `it` statement for each thing you want to test about that method.  The rspec people have a convention (which I use in my JS tests) of using a '#' on the method `describe` for an instance method, and a "." for a `describe` of a static method.

Now, if you adopt all of the above, and you want to test (for instance) that your `View`'s click-handling method triggers a certain event on the `View`'s `Model`, it would look something like this:

```
define([
    'education/eet/views/editdestinationview'
], function (EditDestinationView) {
    describe('EditDestinationView', function () {
        var view;
        beforeEach(function () {
            // do setup work that applies to all EditDestinationView tests
            view = new EditDestinationView({model: new Backbone.Model()});
        });
        describe('#handleClick', function () {
            beforeEach(function () {
                // do setup work that applies only to handleClick tests
            });
            it('triggers a foo event', function () {
                var wasTriggered;
                view.model.on('foo', function() {
                    wasTriggered = true;
                });
                view.handleClick();
                expect(wasTriggered).toBe(true);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

P.S. Instead of creating a fake "foo" handler like I did, most people use a mocking library like Sinon.  Using that library our "it" statement could instead be:

```
            it('triggers a foo event', function () {
                var triggerStub = sinon.stub(view.model, 'trigger');
                view.handleClick();
                expect(triggerStub.calledOnce).toBe(true);
                expect(triggerStub.args[0][0]).toBe('foo');
                //NOTE: args[0][0] == first arg of first call
            });
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your kind help but I am not getting it working :-( When testing a view, shall I 'import' the model and controller in the 'define'? Sorry if the question is very basic but I am brand new to Jasmine.

Comment: In the example code I provided the only thing you might need to require is `Backbone` (and even then only if you haven't defined your `Backbone` variable globally).  What error are you getting?